# Search results with no pager and no limit

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-6, themes

I'm pretty new to Drupal, but I guess I know how things work. I separated the Advanced Search Form from the search page and made a block from it (that was part 1). Woohoo. Part 2 is the pager-from-nowhere in the search results. Drupal search results are paged by tens and I can't seem to find a way to change it.

Not a decent way that is.

In search.module, there lives a function do_search where the results are fetched with:

```
pager_query("$select $sort_parameters", 10, 0, $count_select, $arguments);
```

The 10 - I guess - is the 10 results that are fetched. The do_search function is unthemeable, but I really don't want to hack drupal core...

Any ideas?

**I'm using my own theme (no base theme) and Drupal  6.19**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy "search" module to sites/all/modules/custom and then do the modifications in sites/all/modules/custom/search. This is the way to customize the core modules.  Drupal will not look for the updates for the modules that are present in sites/all/modules/custom, so what ever you do the modification they will be permanent.

Please remember to Copy the modules and not to move the modules.

Comment: make sure that u go to admin/build/modules as drupal will only update the paths of modules only when u visit this page.

Comment: Thanks for this solution - works great for now.  theme_preprocess_search_results() has a $variables['pager'] element in it - but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Anyone know why this doesn't work as expected?  Seems like that would be better than copying and hacking the core module, if possible.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hacked Drupal Core module. It's not a good practice .

use this solution https://drupal.org/node/1839912#comment-6729428